# PDO: stripslashes when getting results

Tags: php, pdo, stripslashes

I am using PDO prepared statements so it's adding slashes when it's needed before inserting into the database.

I was wondering the proper way to get the results and display it on the website without showing the slashes.

Is it as easy as just using `echo stripslashes($result->message);`?

Here is what my queries look like:

```
$database->query('INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', array($value1, $value2, $value3));
```

Here is my `query` method:

```
public function query($query, $bind=null)
{
    global $pdo;

    # Prepare Statment
    $this->statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

    # Execute Query
    $this->statement->execute($bind);
}
```

**EDIT: `get_magic_quotes_gpc` was indeed turned on even though WHM (cPanel) said it was off**

Comment: Have you actually tried that to see?

Comment: @andrewsi Yes, and it works. I was wondering if that was the "normal" way of doing it.

Comment: Don't use `global $pdo`, instead, inject it to the query: `public function query(PDO $pdo, $query, $bind=null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_magic_quotes_gpc` was indeed turned on even though WHM (cPanel) said it was off

Answer (score 4):

Prepared statements do not add slashes to your query data. They inject the parameters into the query in the form of placeholder, in such a way that the placeholder is not considered as part of the query, but as part of the data only.

Therefore, no slashed are added, and no need for `stripslashes()`.

If slashes are added for you, make sure you disable prepared statements emulation for your PDO instance:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Comment: Isn't one of the advantages of using PDO because it has features like that, that make queries safer? From what I read about PDO is I don't need to sanitize queries. I'll edit my OP with what my queries look like.

Comment: @Draven: Exactly, you don't need to sanitize your queries, but not because it sanitizes it for you. Because the query is **prepared**. Take this exammple: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?` The ? is a placeholder, that query is compiled (before actual data is injected into the query), **then** data is injected, because the query was already compiled, it doesn't matter what data goes into the placeholder, it won't affect the query.

Comment: That is what I thought. After running more tests today it seems like it only adds slashes to `$_POST` data. Is that right? I assume my queries will still be safe if I do what you suggest?

Comment: @Draven: No, something else adds those slashes for you. Because someone adds slashes, and they don't escape anything thanks to the prepared statement, you see those slashes in your data. Find out who adds those slashes, and kill it. Then, you will reach enlightenment, little grasshopper.

Comment: Weird. Never seen this before. I decided to `echo $_POST['input_name']` and it echo'd with the slashes. So my form is adding the slashes? How?

Comment: @Draven: Run [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-runtime.php), if it return TRUE, magic quotes are enabled.

Comment: I don't know than. Ask this is a separate question. "Why does PHP adds slashes to $_POST when magic quotes are disabled?" And add all the relevant details.

Comment: I changed `get_magic_quotes_runtime` to `get_magic_quotes_gpc` and that returned true.

Comment: Damn, sorry for all this trouble and thank you for helping me. I edit php.ini using WHM (cPanel) and the setting for `get_magic_quotes_gpc` said it was off, but I decided to save it anyway, just in case, and sure enough, it is now off.